# Changing background color using combobox from a different form in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Public Class Form4
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        On Error GoTo SaveErr
        MachineHistoryBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Update(HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)
        MessageBox.Show("OK Complete")
SaveErr:
        Exit Sub
        Dim tempcolor4 As String
        Dim tempcolor1 As String

```
    tempcolor4 = ComboBox4.Text
    tempcolor1 = ComboBox1.Text

    If tempcolor4.Equals("Running") And tempcolor1.Equals("1") Then
        Form9.PictureBox15.BackColor = Color.Green
    ElseIf tempcolor4.Equals("Stop") And tempcolor1.Equals("1") Then
        Form9.PictureBox15.BackColor = Color.Red
    ElseIf tempcolor4.Equals("Setup") And tempcolor1.Equals("1") Then
        Form9.PictureBox15.BackColor = Color.Orange
    ElseIf tempcolor4.Equals("For Setup") And tempcolor1.Equals("1") Then
        Form9.PictureBox15.BackColor = Color.Yellow
    ElseIf tempcolor4.Equals("Idle") And tempcolor1.Equals("1") Then
        Form9.PictureBox15.BackColor = Color.Cyan
    End If
```

End Sub
Private Sub Form4_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'HistoryDataSet.Machine_History' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'HistoryDataSet.Machine_History' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'HistoryDataSet.Machine_History' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Machine_HistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.HistoryDataSet.Machine_History)

```
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    MachineHistoryBindingSource.MovePrevious()
End Sub

Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    MachineHistoryBindingSource.AddNew()
End Sub

Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click
    MachineHistoryBindingSource.MoveNext()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MachineHistoryBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: What are the items in the comboBox? What code have you tried?

Comment: you are using winforms, right?

Comment: If you havent tried anything and have no code, then you have not done enough research or spent enough effort on *your* problem.  This is not a tutorial site.  Read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: Google Adding items to combo box, color.FromName, Me.BackColor, ComboBox event handlers and Button event handlers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there seems to have been no effort researching the problem.

Comment: i tried to make the code, please see attached code. this code is working in my form 1. but i want when picturebox2 back color change, i want the picturebox2 back color in my form 2 change as well.

Comment: Public Class Form9
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim tempcolor As String
        tempcolor = ComboBox1.Text

        If tempcolor.Equals("Running") Then
            PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Green
        ElseIf tempcolor.Equals("Stop") Then
            PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Red
        ElseIf tempcolor.Equals("Setup") Then
            PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Orange
        End If
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: OK. Thanks for adding code, though you should edit your question and include it there rather than add it as a comment. I've already done it for you, to avoid closing the question as off-topic.

Comment: Ah sorry - I missed the comment about changing in form2. looking at it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Well, the code you have in the button.click event works fine. I presume that you want the colour to change as soon as you select "Running","Stopped" or "Setup"

Instead of having the code in the `Button1.Click` event handler, it should be placed in a `ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged` event handler. Like this ..

It uses `Select Case` instead of `If..Then` for less code. Also I've added the `With..End With` statement so that it isnt necessary to keep typing `PictureBox2`

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Select Case ComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        Case "Running"
            PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Green
            Form2.PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Green
        Case "Stop"
            PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Red
            Form2.PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Red
        Case "Setup"
            PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Orange
            Form2.PictureBox2.BackColor = Color.Orange

    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. David, this code working on my  program as well. but still don't know how to change the background color of my picture box in Form 2.

Comment: See my updated answer. I thought I had put this code in already. Sorry. I also removed the With statements to reduce confusion while dealing with two forms.

Comment: Hi Mr David,

You help me a lot regarding my question of change back color in stack overflow sites.
before its working but right now when i save the data into data grid view and access the back color from other form has no response.
Please help me.
Edited Code on top.